# Changing image on click of textbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make an html form that has multiple text box.  I would like to change the image based on the active text box.  The code I wrote works fine but would be very repetitive if I want to use more then a few changes.

Is there a better way to do this?

html:

```
<div class="img"<img src=image.jpg" id="f1" /> </div>

<form action = "page.php" method = "post">
 <label> Spec </label> <input type= "text" name = "t1" onclick="changeImage()" value = "" /><br>
 <label> Spec 2 </label> <input type="text" name = "t2" onclick = "changeImage1()" value = "" /> <br>
```

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function changeImage() {
    var t = document.getElementById('f1');
        t.src='image1.jpg';
   }
  function changeImage1() {
    var t = document.getElementById('f1');
        t.src='image2.jpg';
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Modern solution**

You can use the new custom attribute `data-something` to store the correct image.
then in javascript check if the element has the correct attribute and show the result.

**js**

```
var form=document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0],
    div=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

form.onclick=function(e){
 !e.target.dataset.img||
 (div.firstChild.src='http://placekitten.com/'+e.target.dataset.img);
}
```

**html**

```
<div><img src="default.png"></div>
<form>
<label><input name="a" data-img="50/200"> a</label>
<label><input name="b" data-img="100/200"> b</label>
<label><input name="c" data-img="150/200"> c</label>
<label><input name="d" data-img="200/200"> d</label>
</form>
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/z5Wu7/

**EDIT**

shorter version with default img.

```
form.onclick=function(e){
 div.firstChild.src='url/'+(e.target.dataset.img||'default.jpg')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the image filename as a `data-*` attribute, and use unobtrusive JavaScript to assign the event handler to all inputs. Also, the `onfocus` event would be more appropriate than `onclick`, because it handles other scenarios such as pressing the tab key to change the active input.

```
<input type= "text" name = "t1" data-image="image1.jpg" value = "" />
<input type= "text" name = "t2" data-image="image2.jpg" value = "" />
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
    var image =  document.getElementById('f1');

    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        inputs[i].onfocus = function(){
            image.src = this.getAttribute('data-image');
        };
    }
};
```

Note: this grabs all inputs on the page but you can filter it by class or some other criteria as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var states = [];
states[0] = 'image1.png';
states[1] = 'image2.png';
states[2] = 'image3.png';
var currentState = 0;

function changeImage()
{
    var t = document.getElementById('f1');
    var src = states[currentState];
        t.src= src;
    currentState++;
    if(currentState == state.length)
    {
       currentState = 0;
    }

}
```

if you want to select a specific image, try to bind a parameter into the html tag and pass it to the function parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="img"><img src="image.jpg" id="f1" /> </div>


    <form action = "page.php" method = "post">
      <label> Spec </label> <input type= "text" name = "t1"  value = "" /><br>
      <label> Spec 2 </label> <input type="text" name = "t2" value = "" /> <br>
    </form>

    <script>
    function changeImage() { 
        var  specImage = document.getElementById("f1"),
             specs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        Array.prototype.map.call(specs, function(spec, index) {
            spec.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                specImage.src = "image" + index + ".jpg";
            });
        });
    }
    changeImage();
    </script>
```

Note: This will select all input on the page, i suggest to query the elements by class instead.